# Fill color in polygons using attribute variable in GMT (Generic Mapping Tool)

Tags: shapefile, gmt

I want to FILL colors of the polygon (converted from .shp ESRI shapefile) based on an attribute (here OBJECTID, Area) from lookup color (.cpt), but I am getting colored outline of each polygon. I attached my result (polygon.png) using below command.

psxy river_b.gmt $range $proj -X2i -Y3i -Ba1WESN -aZ=OBJECTID -Criver_b.cpt -K -P >! $outfile

Please suggest me which gmt command will work here.

[image]

I am attaching a example what kind of map I want to make in GMT. [image]

Comment: Open the .gmt file with a text editor. Don't you really see any attributes in there?

Comment: Thanks Damini, I can see attributes. It shows attribute differently not in a column.  But in a row. That's why I was not able to find it. still can you help me to make above plots  in gmt software. Please let me know.

Comment: I reformatted my question. Please suggest me to solve above issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, same question and answer made in https://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/boards/1/topics/7553