# GMT Pen name c not recognized - Trying to fill polygons

Tags: gmt

I am trying to fill my polygons like this person tried:
[Fill color in polygons using attribute variable in GMT (Generic Mapping Tool)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294021/fill-color-in-polygons-using-attribute-variable-in-gmt-generic-mapping-tool) with some hints here:
https://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/boards/1/topics/7553
They suggest to:

> Try what the man page for psxy -W says:
>   +c Controls how pens and fills are affected if a CPT is specified via -C:
>   Append l to let pen colors follow the CPT setting.
>   Append f to let fill/font colors follow the CPT setting.

I tried but I get the error:

> psxy: Pen name c not recognized!

when I try the solution suggested.

Code drawing the borders of the geologic layers with the palette colors:

```
gmt psxy "$repo/geology.gmt" $reg $proj -aZ=Code -C$colornames
-Zzval  -O -K
```

Code supposed to fill in those layers with the palette colors, but which gives an error:

```
gmt psxy "$repo/geology.gmt" $reg $proj  -W+c -aZ=Code -C$colornames -Zzval  -O -K
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it seems I forgot to close the polygons, thus they couldn't be filled!!
This worked:

```
gmt psxy "$repo/geology.gmt" $reg $proj -L -aZ=Code -C$colornames -Zzval -O -K
```

Answer (score 0):

-W alone uses the default pen but when you want to add modifiers (+c) here, I believe that you have to state also a pen. Try -W1p+c

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I got the same message. I had to add -L.